# Cocos 2d (Android) app crashes on my phone, and setup appears to be a bit wierd

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

Welp after much trying I have found my way to a tutorial that fully says how to set up cocos 2d for android.  Unfortunately three things are happening that I can not explain.

Issue 1

Apon opening eclipse it greets me with the folloiwng alert:

```
    [2016-05-20 22:32:29 - Android SDK] Error when loading the SDK:

 Error: Error parsing C:\Cocos2d\eclipse\sdk\system-images\android-23\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
    cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.
    Error: Error parsing C:\Cocos2d\eclipse\sdk\system-images\android-23\android-wear\x86\devices.xml
    cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.
```

Issue 2

When looking in the device navigator my phone gets a yellow triangle by it even though it is the same version as the sdk. However eclipse still accepts it so I dont know if that is really an issue.

Issue 3

When launching on my device the console gives this message and the app crashes.

```
05-20 22:27:54.940: D/ResourcesManager(27703): creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.broccoli.mygame-1/base.apk
05-20 22:27:54.990: D/AndroidRuntime(27703): Shutting down VM
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703): Process: com.broccoli.mygame, PID: 27703
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.broccoli.mygame-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libMyGame.so"
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onLoadNativeLibraries(Cocos2dxActivity.java:246)
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onCreate(Cocos2dxActivity.java:260)
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
05-20 22:27:54.990: E/AndroidRuntime(27703):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

I am using:

```
-Cocos2d-x-3.11 
- Apache ant 1.9.7
- Python 27 
- Android ndk r11c
- Android sdk with a ton of add the extra sdk's.
- Targeting android 5.0.1
- Java
- Eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve Issue 3 "couldn't find "libMyGame.so", you need to check what values you have in application manifest xml file and location of libMyGame.so.

1.
See Application tag, to load "libMygame.so" put android:value="MyGame" (without lib prefix) inside meta-data tag.

```
<!-- your Application tag -->
<!-- Tell Cocos2dxActivity the name of our .so -->
<meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="MyGame" />
```

2. Check if your *.so library is inside produced apk lib folder in  /data/app/com.broccoli.mygame-1/base.apk Exact location depends on your android target. If not check your project sources and lib folder location.
   Typical place for example is /proj.android/libs/armeabi-v7a/libMygame.so